# Unable to Run Hive Sub Query

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

My problem statement is : I want to get those customer who has only those orders which have status closed.Customer should not have even single order which has other status.

I have a Orders table with schema as `Order_id` , `Order_customer_id` , `Order_date` , `Order_status`.

There are 9 Order status which are 'COMPLETE' , 'PROCESSING','PAYMENT_REVIEW','PENDING' ,'ON_HOLD' ,'CANCELED','SUSPECTED_FRAUD','PENDING_PAYMENT'  and 'CLOSED'.

When I am running below query , I am not getting the desired result.
Please help me in understanding what i am doing wrong.

Query :

```
select order_customer_id ,count(*) from orders where order_customer_id
 IN (select order_customer_id from orders where order_status NOT IN 
('COMPLETE' , 'PROCESSING','PAYMENT_REVIEW','PENDING' ,'ON_HOLD' ,'CANCELED','SUSPECTED_FRAUD','PENDING_PAYMENT'))
 group by order_customer_id;
```

*After executing the query , I am getting those customer who is even having Orders in other status.*

Answer (score 1):

You don't enforce the condition that your customer must have only `Closed` orders. you collect all `closed` orders from all customers in your inner query.

You could use `collect_set` to solve this:

```
select order_customer_id ,count from 
(select order_customer_id,collect_set(order_status),count(*) as count from orders where
   size(collect_set(order_status)) = 1 and 
   collect_set(order_status)[0] = 'CLOSED'  
   group by order_customer_id) inner;
```